# ClearInterval no funciona en slider

Tags: javascript

Al dar click en los botones `#slider-but1`, `#slider-but2` o `slider-but3` para que cambie la imagen, quiero que detener el setInterval llamado `interval` y volverlo a crear. De esa manera, al darle click a alguna imagen, estará visible el tiempo correcto.

El problema es que me está ignorando el `clearInterval`, y ejecuta nuevamente el `setInterval`, haciendo que cada vez vaya más rápido el cambio de imágenes. ¿A qué se debe ésto?

```js
var interval = setInterval(tiempo, 3500);

function displaySlider1(){
 document.getElementById('slider1').style.visibility="visible";
 document.getElementById('slider1').style.opacity=1;
 document.getElementById('slider1').style.height="100vh";
}

function hideSlider1(){
 document.getElementById('slider1').style.visibility="hiden";
 document.getElementById('slider1').style.opacity=0;
 document.getElementById('slider1').style.height=0;
}

function displaySlider2(){
 document.getElementById('slider2').style.visibility="visible";
 document.getElementById('slider2').style.opacity=1;
 document.getElementById('slider2').style.height="100vh";
}

function hideSlider2(){
 document.getElementById('slider2').style.visibility="hiden";
 document.getElementById('slider2').style.opacity=0;
 document.getElementById('slider2').style.height=0;
}

function displaySlider3(){
 document.getElementById('slider3').style.visibility="visible";
 document.getElementById('slider3').style.opacity=1;
 document.getElementById('slider3').style.height="100vh";
}

function hideSlider3(){
 document.getElementById('slider3').style.visibility="hiden";
 document.getElementById('slider3').style.opacity=0;
 document.getElementById('slider3').style.height=0;
}

function showSlider1(){
 clearInterval(interval)
 hideSlider2();
 hideSlider3();
 displaySlider1();
  var interval = setInterval(tiempo, 3500);
 interval;
}

function showSlider2(){
 clearInterval(interval)
 hideSlider1();
 hideSlider3();
 displaySlider2();
  var interval = setInterval(tiempo, 3500);
 interval;
}

function showSlider3(){
 clearInterval(interval)
 hideSlider1();
 hideSlider2();
 displaySlider3();
  var interval = setInterval(tiempo, 3500);
 interval;
}

function tiempo(){
 if(slider1.style.opacity ==  1){
  showSlider2();
 }else if(slider2.style.opacity ==  1){
  showSlider3();
 }else if(slider3.style.opacity ==  1){
  showSlider1();
 }
}

interval;
```

```css
.slider{
 position: relative;
}

.slider-buttons-set{
 z-index:1;
 display:flex;
 flex-flow:row nowrap;
 justify-content: space-around;
 align-items: flex-end;
 align-items: flex-end;
    padding: 0 17%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.slider-buttons{
 background-color: #d0e4ed;
 width:30%;
 height:9px;
 border:0 solid transparent;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.slider-img{
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;
     background-origin: content-box;
     width:100%;
     transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s ease;
     top:0;
     position:absolute;
     right:0;
     z-index:-1;
    }
    
    #slider1{ background-color:#6bd2db; }
    #slider2{ background-color:#ffc0cb; }
    #slider3{ background-color:#646cdd; }
```

```html
<div class="slider">
<div class="slider-buttons-set">
     <button class="slider-buttons" id="slider-but1" onclick="showSlider1()"></button>
     <button class="slider-buttons" id="slider-but2" onclick="showSlider2()"></button>
     <button class="slider-buttons" id="slider-but3" onclick="showSlider3()"></button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="slider-img" id="slider1" style="visibility: visible;opacity: 1; height:100vh;"></div>
    
    <div class="slider-img" id="slider2" style="visibility: hidden;opacity: 0;"></div>
    
    <div class="slider-img" id="slider3" style="visibility: hidden;opacity: 0;"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: intenta quitar en la funciones `showSlider` las lineas   `var interval = setInterval(tiempo, 3500);
 interval;` eso es lo que quieres?

Comment: si no lo agrego entonces no ejecuta la variable `interval`

Comment: debes tener una variable global del interval, ya que cuando haces var estas creando otra variable y asi cada vez que da click, creo que la respuesta que dieron es lo que quieres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías evitar las redeclaraciones de `interval`, lo que sucede es asignar un numero diferente al que el `setinterval` asigna

por lo tanto es mejore tener una variable global asignada y en base a esa limpiar y asignar los valores nuevos del `setInterval`

```js
var interval = setInterval(tiempo, 3500);

function displaySlider1() {
  document.getElementById('slider1').style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById('slider1').style.opacity = 1;
  document.getElementById('slider1').style.height = "100vh";
}

function hideSlider1() {
  document.getElementById('slider1').style.visibility = "hiden";
  document.getElementById('slider1').style.opacity = 0;
  document.getElementById('slider1').style.height = 0;
}

function displaySlider2() {
  document.getElementById('slider2').style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById('slider2').style.opacity = 1;
  document.getElementById('slider2').style.height = "100vh";
}

function hideSlider2() {
  document.getElementById('slider2').style.visibility = "hiden";
  document.getElementById('slider2').style.opacity = 0;
  document.getElementById('slider2').style.height = 0;
}

function displaySlider3() {
  document.getElementById('slider3').style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById('slider3').style.opacity = 1;
  document.getElementById('slider3').style.height = "100vh";
}

function hideSlider3() {
  document.getElementById('slider3').style.visibility = "hiden";
  document.getElementById('slider3').style.opacity = 0;
  document.getElementById('slider3').style.height = 0;
}

function showSlider1() {
  clearInterval(interval)
  hideSlider2();
  hideSlider3();
  displaySlider1();
  interval = setInterval(tiempo, 3500);
  interval;
}

function showSlider2() {
  clearInterval(interval)
  hideSlider1();
  hideSlider3();
  displaySlider2();
  interval = setInterval(tiempo, 3500);
  interval;
}

function showSlider3() {
  clearInterval(interval)
  hideSlider1();
  hideSlider2();
  displaySlider3();
  interval = setInterval(tiempo, 3500);
  interval;
}

function tiempo() {
  if (slider1.style.opacity == 1) {
    showSlider2();
  } else if (slider2.style.opacity == 1) {
    showSlider3();
  } else if (slider3.style.opacity == 1) {
    showSlider1();
  }
}

interval;
```

```css
.slider {
  position: relative;
}

.slider-buttons-set {
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding: 0 17%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.slider-buttons {
  background-color: #d0e4ed;
  width: 30%;
  height: 9px;
  border: 0 solid transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider-img {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-origin: content-box;
  width: 100%;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s ease;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

#slider1 {
  background-color: #6bd2db;
}

#slider2 {
  background-color: #ffc0cb;
}

#slider3 {
  background-color: #646cdd;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider-buttons-set">
    <button class="slider-buttons" id="slider-but1" onclick="showSlider1()"></button>
    <button class="slider-buttons" id="slider-but2" onclick="showSlider2()"></button>
    <button class="slider-buttons" id="slider-but3" onclick="showSlider3()"></button>
  </div>

  <div class="slider-img" id="slider1" style="visibility: visible;opacity: 1; height:100vh;"></div>

  <div class="slider-img" id="slider2" style="visibility: hidden;opacity: 0;"></div>

  <div class="slider-img" id="slider3" style="visibility: hidden;opacity: 0;"></div>
</div>
```